# Google Maps Developers go to specific Location

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing an app which tells the user the best options that he can go. For this I am using google maps technology.

What I currently did is this:

1. show the user his current location
2. show the user the possibilities where he can go to (with Markers and info window)
3. and finally a list underneath the map with the name of the place of each marker marked on the map.

Now near the list I have a button call See Location and I would like that when the user clicks on the button, it directs him to that specific marker and open the info tab.

Currently my code consists of the following:

```
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: CurrentLoc,
            map: map
        });

        document.getElementById('LocationList').innerHTML = '';

        var request = {
            location: CurrentLoc,
            radius: '2000',
            types: ['park']
        };

        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.nearbySearch(request, callback);

    function callback(results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

            clearOverlays();
            htmlSugLoc = '<ul id="List" class="List ui-listview" data-role="listview">';

            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var place = results[i];
                createMarker(results[i],i);
            }

            htmlSugLoc += '</ul>';
            document.getElementById('LocationList').innerHTML = htmlSugLoc;

        }
        else {
            clearOverlays();

            document.getElementById('LocationList').innerHTML = "<p>No Suitable Locations were found</p>";

            //alert('No Locations were found');
        }
    }


        function createMarker(place,selectID) {

        var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
        var imageStar = "images/star.png";

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            icon: imageStar,
            position: place.geometry.location
        });

        var infowindow  = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.setContent(place.name);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });

        markersArray.push(marker);

        var odd = selectID % 2;
        if (odd == true) {
            htmlSugLoc += '<li style="background-color:#CCCCCC;" class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-c ui-first-child">';
        }
        else {
            htmlSugLoc += '<li style="background-color:#E6E6E6;" class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-c ui-first-child">';
        }

        htmlSugLoc += place.name;

        htmlSugLoc += '<div class="ViewLocation" style="float:right;margin-right:10px;margin-top:-5px;">';
        htmlSugLoc += '<input id="Meet'+selectID+'" type="hidden" value="'+placeLoc+'"/>';
        htmlSugLoc += '<a id="'+selectID+'" href="#" onclick="SeeMeetLocation(this.id);return false;"><img src="images/SeeLocation.png" width="100%" height="100%"/></a>';
        htmlSugLoc += '</div>';

        htmlSugLoc += '</li>';

    }

    // Removes the overlays from the map, but keeps them in the array
    function clearOverlays() {
      if (markersArray) {
        for (i in markersArray) {
          markersArray[i].setMap(null);
        }
      }
    }

function SeeMeetLocation(VariableID) {

    var InputID = "";
    var Placelocation = "";

    InputID = "Meet"+VariableID;


    Placelocation = document.getElementById(InputID).value;
}
```

Also, as you can see the radius right now is fixed 2000. Is it possible that instead of using radius, I use the town/place name for example Manchester,Palermo etc so that it will cover only that location. The Thing is that CurrentLoc (the position) of the user always changes.

Last question that I have is can I somehow show him the distance between him and the marker chosen.

Thanks

Keith Spiteri

Answer (score 1):

In SeeMeetLocation you need to `trigger` the click event on that particular marker.  You might also want to then centre the map on the marker at the same time.  You probably need to pass something to indicate which marker that's on through your call to `SeeMeetLocation`.

```
onclick="SeeMeetLocation(this.id, ' + markersArray.length-1 + ');
```

Then:

```
function SeeMeetLocation(VariableID, marker) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(markersArray[marker], 'click');
    map.setCenter(markersArray[marker].getPosition());
```

Finally, for calculating distances between two points use the [geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical), you could try something like:

```
function calculateDistances(start,end) {
    var distances = {};

    distances.metres = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(start, end);
    distances.km = Math.round(distances.metres / 1000 *10)/10;
    distances.miles = Math.round(distances.metres / 1000 * 0.6214 *10)/10;

    return distances ;
}
```

Make sure and add the `libraries=geometry` parameter when loading in the API.

Comment: Thanks. Two questions answered. Regarding the radius, can something else replace that

Comment: In future instead of asking 3 different questions in the same post, you should post 3 separate questions

Comment: I asked three questions because they relate to each other